# Symfony 4.4 Add current locale to generateURL function

Tags: symfony, routes, locale

I have route configuration like this

```
controllers:
 resource: '../src/Controller/'
 type: annotation
 prefix:
  en: '' 
  '*': '/{_locale}'
```

this works very good, attribute override locale

but when i use generateURL i must always add code to get current locale and set it

how to do it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

```
controllers:
     resource: '../src/Controller/'
     type: annotation
     prefix:
       en: ''
       de: '/{_locale}'
       es: '/{_locale}'
       fr: '/{_locale}'
       hu: '/{_locale}'
       it: '/{_locale}'
       nl: '/{_locale}'
       pl: '/{_locale}'
       pt: '/{_locale}'
       ro: '/{_locale}'
       ru: '/{_locale}'
       tr: '/{_locale}'
```

it work, but how to clean this code?